# Knockout : Push value in ko observable array with dynamic key

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, observable

I want to add push value in array with dynamic key. I use this below code :

```
this.customOptionVal.push({name:value});
```

**this.customOptionVal is ko.observableArray()**

Output of the above code is :

```
0: {name: "stack"}
```

I want to get output like this :

```
mykey: {name: "stack"}
```

How to do this?

Comment: `customOptionVal` must be an array? Can it be just an observable object? like: `ko.observable({});` ?

Comment: In case of arrays, you will always get indices....Keys makes more sense in case of  objects (like dictionaries in C#)

Comment: There are no "keys" in Javascript arrays, only positive integer indexes. You need to explain the intended use case better, so we can suggest a optimal strategy for JS/Knockout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use a simple observable and not an observableArray (because arrays will always use indices and not custom keys), you can set that `customOptionVal` is an observable object: `customOptionVal = ko.observable({})`

Now you can access the object inside the observable with `customOptionVal()`, then you can add your key in this object, something like: `customOptionVal()[yourKeyHere] = {name: "stack"}`.

See below for a better example

```js
var customOptionVal = ko.observable({});
customOptionVal()['myKey'] = {name:"stack"};

console.log(customOptionVal())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Calvin. Yes. customOptionVal must be ko observable array.

Comment: Btw, can you please tell me can I remove array index by specific field value from ko observablearray?

Comment: This is completely another question. But for this, it would be much easier as an object than an array (once again). Suggestion, try to create a custom function to remove the observable, then edit the contents and create another function to convert it back to observable

Comment: Hi @Calvin. Can you please look over that ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54320140/knockout-remove-array-element-by-specific-field-value